# Deferred sending from Outlook 2007 with Exchange 2007

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, outlook-redemption

Is there a way of sending an email from Outlook with some sort of flag that tells Exchange to hold on to the message for 5 minutes before it is actually sent out on the internet?

I know about setting the "Do not deliver before" date in Outlook but that simply keeps the message in the Outlook outbox as far as I can see.

I'm happy to use redemption if it is able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `MailItem.DeferredDeliveryTime` property (which sets the `PR_DEFERRED_DELIVERY_TIME` property) - refer to [this blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2004/07/16/185410.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

At the user level you can set a rule in outlook for all sent mail to be held for a specified number of minutes.  See tip #1 at this [link](http://www.friedbeef.com/4-ways-to-save-time-using-outlook/) for instructions.